# What kind of User data I can collect

Tags: android

I was wondering if I ever need to collect any kind of user data (like their location, which I don't think I should collect now, their IMEI, their google account, app usage time etc), then how much of it I can collect without doing so illegally.

I know there will be issues with all of them, but since I couldn't find any document or question on SO, addressing this topic, telling me what kind of data I can collect, I am here with a question.

Hope to get nice answers.

Wish to mark it as a community wiki.

Comment: If you're really serious about this get a lawyer (or a few). But the basic gist is: don't collect anything **unless** you inform the user that you're collecting **and** get their consent.

Comment: Hey guys he want to do it legally not illegally so please.. :)

Comment: That's nice. I'll be informing the user for sure. but I am concerned about Google's app killing policies

Comment: The basic reason for such collection is to get demographics and stats of app usage.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without the user knowing it?

## NONE.

> 4.3 You agree that if you use the SDK to develop applications for general public users, you will protect the privacy and legal rights of those users. If the users provide you with user names, passwords, or other login information or personal information, your must make the users aware that the information will be available to your application, and you must provide legally adequate privacy notice and protection for those users. If your application stores personal or sensitive information provided by users, it must do so securely. If the user provides your application with Google Account information, your application may only use that information to access the user's Google Account when, and for the limited purposes for which, the user has given you permission to do so.

(from part 4 of the [Terms and Conditions](http://developer.android.com/sdk/terms.html))

Take a look also at [this page about searches](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/index.html)

Comment: nice one, i was also looking for it

Comment: nice one, really. Thanks for the links. although, I am going to notify the users about what information I am going to collect, but wasn't sure about the policies which govern app killing process.

Comment: Okay, And what if the user knows about the data collection and lets the app collect the data?

Comment: @Sheikh as Joachim said in his comment, you should really talk to a lawyer. **Disclaimer: this is not legal advice!** Also, contact Google directly (maybe through the market forum @ http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Android+Market?hl=en ). My view is that you can collect the data provided you specify what data and what will be the use. You should be sure to delete the data from users that request that also.

Comment: Sure. all the queries that I had in my head, are getting resolved one by one. :) on the other note, I was thinking to try to collect usage stats with the UA string that a WebView might give me. how does that sound?

Comment: On a website? Again, you should have some privacy policy link in there. But, honestly, I would ask the details to a trustable source (Google itself, or a lawyer's buffet).